# Telebot Error: ChatBoost Missing Arguments in Infinity Polling - Group Limit Related?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

My Python telebot was working great for a few weeks, but today, this error started to occur:

`(__init__.py:1021 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: ChatBoost.__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'boost_id', 'add_date', and 'expiration_date'"`

Could this be related to the number of groups the bot is in? This error occurs when I run `bot.infinity_polling()` or `bot.polling()`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in pyTelegramBotAPI.

---

This was first mentioned in [Discussion #2174](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/discussions/2174) and is now discussed in [Issue #2175](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/2175).

The original-poster [says](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/2175#issue-2140040007):

> A simple restart seemed to have eliminated the issue ...

So I'd recommend updating to the latest version (if possible) and restart the Bot.